# does magnolia CMS has these features?

Tags: content-management-system, sms, blogs, fax, magnolia

Does magnolia CMS Has these features:

1. could each user send sms?
2. could each user has blog?
3. could each user send fax?

thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

Whether users can send sms or fax depends on whether you connect you Magnolia CMS based system to appropriate SMS/Fax gateway. If you do, there is nothing stopping you from having template on a webpage that would do so or app in admin central that would allow authorised users to send such messages. Similarly you can have custom command that would send sms notification about page being published instead of sending mail. However it all boils down to connecting your installation to such a gateway first.

As for the blogs, there is a blog module that you can install and use, so yes, you can have blogs for users. However if you are looking for software whose primary use case would be to host and manage blogs you will be happier w/ Wordpress or similar products. Magnolia CMS primary function is a web content management.

HTH,
Jan